# Updating associated record attribute doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A post has many comments. In my code I am trying to change an attribute of the first comment like so:

```
post = Post.find(id)
post.comments.first.title # "initial title"
post.comments.first.title = "foobar"

post.comments.first.title_changed? # false
post.comments.first.title # "initial title"
```

Is this an expected AR behavior? If yes, how can I change attributes of associated records?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is expected.
`post.comments.first.title = "foobar"` just assigns the title but not saves it.

Right way to update is `post.comments.first.update(title: "foobar")`.

Or you need to `post.comments.first.save` after assigning a new title

Comment: What if I don't want to persist the change into a db?

Comment: @spacemonkey, sorry, I didn't understood you question completely. Try to use `comment = post.comments.first` and apply changes on it

Comment: it actually works if I use `comment = post.comments[0]`, but doesn't with `comment = post.comments.first`.

Answer (score 0):

First, assign the comment object to a variable, then make the change to that variable and save

```
post = Post.find(id)
comment = post.comments.first
comment.title = "foobar"
comment.title_changed? # true
comment.save
```